# Json.Net: Trimming an object to save web traffic

Tags: json, json.net

I have a very complex JSON returning from an API. I need to pass only the "first level" to the client side, without all the nested objects contained in it.

For example:

```
  {
    "name": "David",
    "age": 5,
    "school": {
        "name": "Highschool",
        "location": "AZ"
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass to the client side only name & age, not "school". 
Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Where are you calling this API from? A server side method?

Comment: @NickZimmerman, yes, a server side method from a 3rd party.

Comment: Are you calling it from your server side code or client side code?

Comment: Calling the API from the server side, and passing the information to the client side. The idea is to pass as little data as necessary and not the entire bloated object.

Comment: My approach would be to create a dynamic object on the server side with only the properties needed to pass to the client. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: @NickZimmerman, thanks. This solution is the obvious one, I was actually looking for some sort of a library function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the JSON into a `JObject` then copy all the "simple" properties (i.e. those that are not objects and arrays) to a new `JObject`.  Then get the new JSON from the copy.

For example:

```
string json = @"
{
    ""name"": ""David"",
    ""age"": 5,
    ""school"": {
        ""name"": ""Highschool"",
        ""location"": ""AZ""
    }
}";

JObject origObj = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject copyObj = new JObject();
foreach (JProperty prop in origObj.Properties())
{
    if (prop.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object &&
        prop.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array)
    {
        copyObj.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
}

json = copyObj.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The above will output the following:

```
{
  "name": "David",
  "age": 5
}
```